# Calculus 2 inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f:[0,π/2]→R$ be a function $x→\sin(x)$.

Give an example of such a partition $P [0,π/2]$, for which $U_P(f) − L_P(f) <10^{-4}$ holds true.

I've been stuck with this for a while now. I understand the idea that we could pick arbitrarily many points for the partition and we would get the inequality to hold, but I can't seem to show it mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

Since the derivative of $\sin x$ is bounded by $1$ in absolute value it follows that the maximum minus the minimum of this function on any interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ is at most equal to the length of the interval (by MVT). Hence you only need  a partition in which the length of each sub-interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ is less than $\frac 2 {\pi} (10)^{-4}$.

So you could consider the partition of $[0, \frac  {\pi} 2]$ into $N$ equal subintervals where  $N>\frac {\pi^{2}} 4 (10)^{4}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit? I don't quite get it yet.